# Springboot hikari JDBC Connection Pool Cache settings

Tags: hikaricp

Am using a Springboot application and use Jdbc hikari driver, When the DB team points the DB name to different servers my app caches the old ips and not reconnecting to new ips, what is the cache settings to refresh the connection pool